# using any and all in a function together

Tags: python, list, function

I'm new to programming and am trying to figure things out.
so i'm looking to write a for loop that will determine if all elements in a variable list 1 and list 2 are less than 8 and also determine if at least one element in the list is less than 8.
this where my thinking process has gotten me.

```
def check(list_one, val):
    for val in list_one:
        if val>= 8:
            return(all(x < val for x in list_one))
        if val >8:
            return (all(x > val for x in List_two))
       
      list_one = [2,5,6,3]
       list_two = [9,8,11,9]
      val = 8
      if (check(list_one, val)):
        print ( "yes")
      else:
          print("no")



if (check(list_two, val)):
    print ( "yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Comment: 1. Fix the formatting, 2. Can you state your requirements in a clearer way?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and then **ask a question**. It should start with a question word like "how" or "why", and end with a question mark (`?`). So far, you have told us that you are trying to figure something out. That is not even telling us that there is a problem, let alone telling us what the problem is, let alone asking a question about it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, is there a public template for common messages? I'm somewhat new as well, and would like to adhere to it, if that is the case...

Comment: Many people have a variety of their own templates, and they might be sharing them, perhaps even with browser-extension support. I actually write out a custom message every time, though. There are a few built-in shortcuts that simplify this, such as `[ask]`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to find out if a value exists in a list then you can (and probably should in most cases) use the *in* keyword. For example, you can assert that:

```
8 in [1,2,3,8,10] == True
```

...and that...

```
8 in [1,2,3,10] == False
```

If you need to know how many elements there are in a list (which I think is part of the question you're asking) then you need to utilise the *len()* built-in function. For example, you can assert that:

```
len([1,2,3,4,5]) == 5
```